# Where should I put XML Builder code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, builder

I am creating a method to generate an XML document via Ruby Builder.

Where should I put the method that created the XML markup? Should it be a method on the model?

I plan to have the XML document pull from multiple models via associations, so I think I need to have it in the controller or a helper, but I would like some in put on the best place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's practical for you, I'd put it in your views folder.  This lets you follow the traditional pattern of "load stuff in the controller; render stuff in the view," and has the extra perk of keeping what's probably a messy and very specific method in its own file and out of the way.

Now, I'm not sure if there's a Ruby Builder template format, but you could always just wrap your code in `<%= ... %>` and treat it like a regular ERB file - should work about the same.

Hope that helps!

Comment: OK, i'll proceed with it in the view folder for that controller. although the documentation says I should user builder for xml. Thank You

Comment: Builder could not handle some of the namespace issues I am dealing with so I have been forced to switch to nokogiri, how would I handle file placement in that case?

Comment: @opensourcechris - I'd still keep it in the views folder.  Exactly how to handle rendering depends on what your data looks like - if it's simple, you can always use the `<%= ... %>` trick.  If it's more complex you could look at [defining your own render format](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/render-options-in-rails-3/).  Then again, you could just stick it in /lib - don't let my personal preferences become your technical difficulties!

Comment: Currently I have my nokogiri code in a file called nokoxml.rb Should I rename this file to nokoxml.builder.xml? So when I render my nokoxml method in my controller it will automatically run the code in nokoxml.builder.xml ? Is that how it will work?

Comment: @opensourcechris - I'm getting out of my depth here (never used Nokogiri like this before), but I can point you to a [minimal working example](https://github.com/mattetti/noko-vs-builder-benchmark) (and the [blog post](http://railsontherun.com/2010/02/22/speed-up-your-rails-xml-responses/) that explains its origins).  He set up a special template handler for the ".nxml" file extension (in only 13 lines!): see lib/nbuilder.rb.  Look at the controllers and views, too, for details, but it seems very simple.  Cheers!

Comment: This example wont run, it doesnt appear to even have a gem file. 'rails s' does nothing from the application root. My application is a Rails 3 application. Thank you though

Comment: Sorry about that (I didn't actually test it, as you may have guessed).  Hopefully the source code can still be helpful.  Good luck!

Comment: hey no problem man, it actually ran, but did not evaluate the nokogiri code, i learned a thing or two about templates though. Thank God for 'git branch -d xml' LOL